# Force users to run setup.exe instead of *.msi

Tags: windows-installer, installation, uac

I've been searching the solution for a while but ended up finding nothing. I would like to ask with Microsoft Setup Project, is there any way to force user to run setup from setup.exe instead of msi file? I tried some solution such as add Launch Condition but do not know how to pass parameter from setup.exe to the msi file...

The reason I ask this is because I need to run some exe files in the setup process and those files require administrator privilege. As you know already we cannot add something like manifest file to require admin privilege for msi file.

I would appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not supported by the Visual Studio setup EXE.

A solution is to wrap all your installation files into a self-extracting EXE archive. This archive can launch your setup EXE after extraction. For example, you can use IExpress: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd346760.aspx

Another solution is to use a different setup authoring tool which supports this directly:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

Comment: This solution requires more effort which I don't prefer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As opposed to what? If you want to change the behavior, you will have to make some kind of effort.

Comment: It is supported by Setup project (by adding a custom action that aborts installation if a custom property is not passed from msiexec command line) but that is way more than the effort needed for a self-extracting executable.

Comment: @Cosmin Thank you, by taking more efforts, I mean when I have to build the setup package over and over again. My job requires new releases at a frequent rate so I would prefer some permanent solution so after that I just need to build the setup by one single step.

Comment: @ShengJiang Could you explain more detail? I know a way to let msi file require some properties to be true, but I don't know how to pass that value from Setup.exe.

Comment: The custom action approach suggested by Sheng Jiang will show the Fatal Error dialog, like the installation is crashing. For me it's not a good user experience. Regarding the self-extracting EXE, you can add its creating process as a post-build event in your Visual Studio setup project.

Comment: @CosminPirvu Do you know how to make that self-extracting EXE to require administrator role? Usually a manifest file is used but in this case I have no idea. Thank you.